# Extending RadioButton with own style in constructor

Tags: android, radio-button, android-drawable, android-styles

I'd like to know why my code doesn't work the way I think it should work. I extended the original `RadioButton` widget with one little change. Here is the code:

```
<!-- language: java -->

public class RadioButton extends android.widget.RadioButton {
    public RadioButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.style.MyRadioButton);
    }

    public RadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

This change is `R.style.MyRadioButton` in constructor. Next I entered following line to my `styles.xml`:

```
<!-- language: xml -->

<style name="MyRadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton" />
```

`Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton` is `style` which defines `drawable` for `RadioButton`.
To use my own `RadioButton` I made a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Default radio button" />

        <com.example.test.RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My radio button" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I think I did is I inherited style from default `RadioButton` and use that style in constructor (the same way it is done in original `RadioButton` source code). Problem is that my `RadioButton` doesn't show any `drawable`, just text and I was wondering why?

It also does not react on click because tapping it does not uncheck "Default radio button" despite the fact both are in `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a problem in my code.

Android documentation says:

> `defStyleAttr`    An attribute in the current theme that contains a reference to a style resource to apply to this view. If 0, no default style will be applied.

What I did wrong was passing `style` instead of `attr` (reference to style in current theme).
So here is the solution:

```
public RadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, R.attr.myRadioButtonStyle);
}
```

I left code in `styles.xml` untouched:

```
<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton" />
```

But i had to create my custom theme in `themes.xml` and apply it to current `Activity`:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="myRadioButtonStyle">@style/MyRadioButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

And in the `attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyTheme">
    <attr name="myRadioButtonStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

My previous code which did not work was based on someone else's old code where `View` constructor attribute was named `defStyle` what led me to mistake. Android developers fixed documentation by renaming attribute to `defStyleAttr`. Here is an issue which documents it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12683

Last post clearly says:

> The documentation is incorrect. The third constructor must be an attribute, e.g. `R.attr.*`